# Tools for modularizing big CSS files & aggregating smaller CSS files

Tags: css, browser, less, aggregation

My site has a mondo-sized CSS file with site-wide CSS selectors. This single file (**Mondo.css**) has worked well because I want users to take the hit once to download this large file.

However, I've recently made a widget control that exposes a small subset of functionality from the site and for performance reasons I want to have a smaller CSS file (**Widget.css**) that only exposes CSS selectors actually used by the widget.

Are there any *run-time tools* I can use (maybe as browser plugins for Chrome, FF, or IE) that will *analyze the CSS dependencies* and help me to break out a Widget.css file from Mondo.css?  Widget.css would essentially become the base class for a new CSS file called "**Site.css**".

Then, I'd like to have a tool that will let me stitch together Widget.css (the base class) and Site.css (the derived class) into Mondo.css (the aggregated class).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. The **"Dust Me Selectors"** plugin for Firefox does pretty much what I need. It parses a live page and gives you separate lists of used and unused selectors.

I can manually walk through this list to do what I need to do.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

http://www.brothercake.com/dustmeselectors/

Comment: More info: For the 2nd question (aggregation) I was able to use Chirpy 2.0 to do this. Previously, I had only used Chirpy 2.0 to do JS file aggregation and minification, but it turns out that I can create a mondo.chirp.config file that contains both widget.chirp.less and site.chirp.less references. It will expand all of the .less variables and then stitch the two files together. http://chirpy.codeplex.com/releases/view/79914